# Node.js localhost server times out on all requests

Tags: localhost, node.js

I am trying to test-run a very large and complex web application on my local machine (a Dell laptop) using node.js as the server.  Obviously this requires accessing the application through localhost.  It's also secured, so I am using an https url.  Unfortunately, every time I run node.js and try to access the application, it hangs.  First the browser tells me that the certificate is bad (this is normal) and I have to manually tell it to continue to the app.  But after I do that, nothing further happens.  All data requests to localhost time out after two minutes without any response.  There are no error messages in console.  There are no errors in the Network tab.  There is no response at all.

What is going on here and how do I fix it?

Comment: What browser are you using? You don't see anything in the web server console AND the browser console?

Comment: Do you have the right port? Certs are for hostnames and wouldn't care about the Port...

Comment: Journeyman Geek: Yes, I have the right port.  Greg: I've had the same effect in two different browsers, Chrome and MSIE.  No, nothing in either the browser console or in the webserver's console.  It looks like the server isn't finishing its start-up sequence, so the computer sees it as running, but it can't hear or respond to data requests.